# slf4j logger using logback logs multiple times depending on the number of threads

Tags: multithreading, logback, slf4j, sifting-appender

I am using Spring. When a request comes from a controller, I create multiple threads and log content in these threads. However, the content gets logged 2 times for the second thread, 3 times for the third thread and so on.

It might get written multiple times in all the log files if the threads are `async`.

Also, I am not able to delete the log files until I stop Tomcat.

Below is my code:

**LogUtil.java**

```
public class LogUtil {


    public static Marker getMarker() {
        Marker marker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("Finalize");
        marker.add(ClassicConstants.FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER);
        return marker;
    }

    public static void addSiftingAppender(org.slf4j.Logger log) {

        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

        Logger logger = lc.getLogger(log.getName());

        SiftingAppender sa = new SiftingAppender();
        sa.setName("SIFT");
        sa.setContext(lc);

        MDCBasedDiscriminator discriminator = new MDCBasedDiscriminator();
        discriminator.setKey("logFileName");
        discriminator.setDefaultValue("batch0");
        discriminator.start();

        sa.setDiscriminator(discriminator);

        sa.setAppenderFactory(new AppenderFactory<ILoggingEvent>() {

            @Override
            public Appender<ILoggingEvent> buildAppender(Context context,
                    String discriminatingValue) throws JoranException {
                FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
                appender.setName("BATCH-EXECUTION-" + discriminatingValue);
                appender.setContext(context);
                appender.setFile(discriminatingValue + ".log");
                appender.setAppend(true);
                if (appender.isStarted()) {
                    appender.stop();
                }

                PatternLayoutEncoder pl = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
                pl.setContext(context);
                pl.setPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n");
                pl.setImmediateFlush(true);
                if (pl.isStarted()) {
                    pl.stop();
                }
                pl.start();
                appender.setEncoder(pl);

                appender.start();
                return appender;
            }
        });
        if (sa.isStarted()) {
            sa.stop();
        }
        sa.start();
        logger.addAppender(sa);
    }

}
```

**Head.java**

```
public class Head implements Runnable {

    // static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Head.class);

    private Logger log;

    private String name;

    Head(Logger logger, String name) {
        this.log = logger;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LogUtil.addSiftingAppender(log);
        MDC.put("logFileName", getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        log.info("something" + getName());
        log.info(LogUtil.getMarker(), "ended");
        MDC.remove("logFileName");

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLogger(Logger log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

}
```

**IfxDesignerController**

```
@Slf4j
public class IfxDesignerController{

 @RequestMapping(value = "/testsomething", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String
            testsomething()
                    throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        int count2 = 1;
        while (count2 <= 2) {
            Head head = new Head(log, "somename" + count2);
            head.setName("head-nested" + count2);
            head.setLogger(log);
            executor.execute(head);
            count2++;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The log files generated when I make a `GET` request to `testsomething` are as follows:

**head-nested1.log**

```
10:15:50.869 [pool-217-thread-1] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - somethinghead-nested1
10:15:50.869 [pool-217-thread-1] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - somethinghead-nested1
10:15:50.887 [pool-217-thread-1] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - ended
10:15:50.887 [pool-217-thread-1] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - ended
```

**head-nested2.log**

```
10:15:50.955 [pool-217-thread-2] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - somethinghead-nested2
10:15:50.955 [pool-217-thread-2] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - somethinghead-nested2
10:15:50.957 [pool-217-thread-2] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - ended
10:15:50.957 [pool-217-thread-2] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - ended
```

What changes should I make in the logback configuration so that the output is as follows (Desired Output):

**head-nested1.log**

```
10:15:50.869 [pool-217-thread-1] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - somethinghead-nested1
10:15:50.887 [pool-217-thread-1] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - ended
```

**head-nested2.log**

```
10:15:50.955 [pool-217-thread-2] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - somethinghead-nested2
10:15:50.957 [pool-217-thread-2] INFO  c.w.c.h.c.c.i.d.IfxDesignerController - ended
```

Also, I should be able to delete the log files after thread execution

Comment: Why are you adding a new sifting appender for each thread? You started two threads, that means you have added two sifting appenders, each of them is going to handle the log message independently.  And, my personal advise is to config logback by config file instead of programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This seems to solve the problem of multiple logging. However, I am still not able to delete the files even after the thread completion. I don't have access to the config file, so I am trying to add appenders programmatically.

Comment: Why do you think you can delete the file after the thread complete? The appender is added, and is still running after your threads complete.  It is very possibly that it is still opening the file as it is still waiting for more log message to come.  And, I am not sure how the logback config is managed in your project but still, you should ask the people responsible to add the related config instead of doing all these programmatically.  It is simply ruining the idea of SLF4j.  You code is going to fail if someone changed the logging backend

Comment: I thought using `MDC.remove("logFileName");` should automatically release the file. I also tried adding `ClassicConstants.FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER` and reducing the sifting appender timeout. However, I am still not able to delete the file. Is this not the correct way to release the file?

Comment: Removing MDC is obviously have nothing to do with appender.  Sifting appender is only deciding where to write based on value in MDC.  Changing/removing MDC entry means nothing.  There can always be new messages that may use the same MDC value later.  Setting timeout for sifting appender should work, but I doubt the nested appender is actively closed at timeout, or siftingAppender is simply closing timed-out nested-appender when being invoked.